# How to set an invalid date to DateTime field for testing purpose?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime field with which I need to test for an error when user feeds an invalid date. I'm unable to set a invalid date programmatically as it has exception handling mechanism in place when invalid format is provided.

```
  public void VerifyErrorWhenInvalidDateEntered(DateTime scannedDate)
    {
      var Date = scannedDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)  
    }
```

If I call the above method with a invalid date say Feb 31st, the method doesn't take that value, instead it takes DB null value( i.e. 1/1/0001)

```
   VerifyErrorWhenInvalidDateEntered(new DateTime(31/2/2016)
```

Is there anyway we can specify an invalid date to DateTiem field?. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: its better to do DateTime.Parse("1/23/0001") and catch the error.

Comment: Given this code, I think you are trying to test the wrong thing. The method you show should get the date, given a _valid_ datetime. Therefore, you should not have to test for impossible dates anymore at this point

Comment: when we use datetime controls, we cant choose invalid date so im afraid if you encounter this scenario.